# Powershell Get a specific process counter with id process

Tags: powershell, process, counter

I want to get specific counters for processes that I have process id's for. However I can't think of a way to use where-object to match the process for the counter.
Like

```
Where Gc '\process(*)\id process -eq 456 gc '\process($name)\working set'
```

So use the process id to retrieve the name and get the working set (or something to that effect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get counters for a process name so first get the process name by using its Id and then embed the process name in the counter. For example:

```
$id = # your process id
$proc = (Get-Process -Id $id).Name
Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($proc)\% Processor Time"
```

Comment: You can wrap it in a foreach call, pipe in your proc IDs and get the info for each one. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: @KenJ I add an answer that works for multiple instances of a process.

Answer (score 9):

It seems a bit convoluted to get the correct performance counter path for a process with multiple instances of the same process name:

```
$proc_id=6580
$proc_path=((Get-Counter "\Process(*)\ID Process").CounterSamples | ? {$_.RawValue -eq $proc_id}).Path
Get-Counter ($proc_path -replace "\\id process$","\% Processor Time")

Timestamp                 CounterSamples
---------                 --------------
11/20/2014 5:39:15 PM     \\myhost\process(conhost#2)\% processor time :
                          0
```

Comment: Yours should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer is definitely wrong (just what everyone talks on the internet, fully unaware that you may have more than one processes with the same "name"). The answer by @JPBlanc is on the right track but too complicated, and yours is the simplification or streamlining of that idea, one that I had also just derived from JPBlanc's proposal. Still I am now abandoning all use of Get-Counter and just monitor my processes by (Get-Process).CPU value where I repeatedly check its increase to find how busy or not it is.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a solution that also include process with multiple instance IDs you can use :

```
$p = $((Get-Counter '\Process(*)\ID Process' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples | % {[regex]$a = "^.*\($([regex]::Escape($_.InstanceName))(.*)\).*$";[PSCustomObject]@{InstanceName=$_.InstanceName;PID=$_.CookedValue;InstanceId=$a.Matches($($_.Path)).groups[1].value}})
# In french, use '\processus(*)\id de processus' for the counter name
$id = # your process id
$p1 = $p | where {$_.PID -eq $id}
Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($($p1.InstanceName+$p1.InstanceId))\% Processor Time"
# In french, use "\Processus($($p1.InstanceName+$p1.InstanceId))\% temps processeur" for the counter name
```

Or if you avoid to use Get-Counter and wait the sample interval, try use WMI:

```
$id = YourProcessIdHere
(gwmi -class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process -Namespace "root\CIMV2" | ? {$_.IdProcess -eq $id}).Name;
```

Comment: The first filter can be as: `Get-Counter '\Process($InstanceName*)\ID Process' ..`. This will also be slightly faster, especially for many processes. The secondary match (although is can be simplified) is still required, in the odd case where instance names are prefixes of each other.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to obtain *some* performance information with the Get-Process commandlet directly and avoid the need to resolve an instance ID.

For the case of the memory working set, just filter the output for the process id you want using `where-object`, then select the parameters you're interested in:

```
get-process | where-object{ $_.id -eq 456 } | select name,workingset
```

Comment: Works great in Windows 2003 since working set - private doesn't exist!