# Powershell get process name (with #) by PID when multiple instances

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use `Get-Counter '\process(APPNAME)\% processor time` however for many processes `APPNAME` repeats. I can use `APPNAME#1`, `APPNAME#2`, `APPNAME#3` in `Get-Counter '\process(APPNAME#2)\% processor time`. However, I can't find how to get the "full" appname (i.e the one that has # in it) from just the PID, is this possible?

The second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067565/powershell-get-a-specific-process-counter-with-id-process) seems to explain it, but I don't understand exactly what they are doing.

Comment: Are you just looking for something like this? `Get-Process -id 5124 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Comment: Nope, that returns (for example) `svchost` but there are 10 `svchost` process running. So I need something that returns `svchost#2` so I can use that in `Get-Counter '\process(svchost#2)\% processor time`

Comment: What about the "last" answer to the question you linked http://stackoverflow.com/a/27052843/3829407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to help you on this accurately because counters are culture sensitive and I'am too lazy to start my US VM.

You can find the PID of a process using :

```
Get-Counter '\\ComputerName\processus(chrome#4)\id de processus'
```

For me it gives :

```
Timestamp                 CounterSamples                                                                                      
---------                 --------------                                                                                      
29/10/2015 08:31:55       \\ComputerName\processus(chrome#4)\id de processus :                                                   
                          3296
```

For UK or US I would try :

```
 Get-Counter '\\ComputerName\process(chrome#4)\process id'
```

This One Line (that you have to adapt to your culture) gives a process list with PIDs and counter instance Id.

```
(Get-Counter '\processus(*)\id de processus').CounterSamples | % {[regex]$a = "^.*\($([regex]::Escape($_.InstanceName))(.*)\).*$";[PSCustomObject]@{InstanceName=$_.InstanceName;PID=$_.CookedValue;InstanceId=$a.Matches($($_.Path)).groups[1].value}}
```

---

Edited :

So here is a solution with the PID in input :

```
$p = $((Get-Counter '\processus(*)\id de processus' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples | % {[regex]$a = "^.*\($([regex]::Escape($_.InstanceName))(.*)\).*$";[PSCustomObject]@{InstanceName=$_.InstanceName;PID=$_.CookedValue;InstanceId=$a.Matches($($_.Path)).groups[1].value}})
$id = # your process id
$p1 = $p | where {$_.PID -eq $id}
Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($($p1.InstanceName+$p1.InstanceId))\% Processor Time"
# In french
# Get-Counter -Counter "\Processus($($p1.InstanceName+$p1.InstanceId))\% temps processeur"
```

Comment: The problem is I don't have, for your example, `(chrome#)`, all I have is the process PID

Comment: @RedRaven I edited the answer to use the one line in order to give a solution with the PID in input.

Answer (score -1):

you need something like this, select the items you need, and after that join them together.

```
Get-Process | Select ProcessName,Id | % {$_.ProcessName + " " + $_.Id}
```

Comment: This returns the `name` and the some integer value, not what I am looking for. Is there an item that would give me the `#2` I am looking for?

Comment: Do you want to just add #2,#3,#4 not depending on the process id?