# CPU usage in percentage in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want the CPU to be displayed as a percentage at the end of the code I wrote. Is there a way?

this is my code

```
Get-Process svchost |  % $_.CPU
```

Hardly made it this far, only last episode left

Comment: That does not give you a usable CPU usage counter. Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943928/listing-processes-by-cpu-usage-percentage-in-powershell. You should find your answer there

Comment: `CPU` is the [TotalProcessorTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime?view=net-7.0). Don't think that's what you actually mean by CPU Usage

Comment: @Max I saw this post before, but I want to have the percentage in this code format, the order of the output display is important to me

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon No, I don't mean that

Comment: What do you mean by percentage then? What should your output look like based off what?

Comment: The output has three parts, I want to show the amount of CPU in percentage or convert to percentage

Comment: @Superuser what do you mean by code format? You can always combine several results in a custom PS Object and display your data how you want

Comment: @Max I mean the code structure that creates the display order

Comment: @Superuser That does not make sense. You either have code that works and gets the job done, or you don't. It does not matter how the structure or looks change. The result is what matters...

Comment: @Max Well, this code doesn't show the result I want, I'm sure there is a way

Comment: It is until unclear how the output from should look like. I'm voting to close this question as it's in need of details and clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Santiago for pointing out the issue that it was the reading for the same svchost instance everytime, this is fixed now.
The code below borrows heavily from this thread: [Powershell Get a specific process counter with id process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067565/powershell-get-a-specific-process-counter-with-id-process)
to get the correct reading.

This gets you the Path, the Id and %.

```
$procResult = Get-Process -Name svchost
$resultObjects = @();
foreach ($result in $procResult) {    
    $p = $((Get-Counter '\Process(*)\ID Process' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).CounterSamples | % { [regex]$a = "^.*\($([regex]::Escape($_.InstanceName))(.*)\).*$";[PSCustomObject]@{InstanceName=$_.InstanceName;PID=$_.CookedValue;InstanceId=$a.Matches($($_.Path)).groups[1].value}})
    $target = $p | where { $_.PID -eq $result.Id }
    $counterResult = Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($($target.InstanceName+$target.InstanceId))\% Processor Time" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($null -eq $counterResult) {
        continue;
    }
    $resultObjects += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Path = $result.Path
        Id = $result.Id
        CPU = $counterResult.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue
    }
}
$resultObjects | ft
```

You won't get the CPU usage in % with your code above. I really do not know why you insist on not changing the structure of your code as the structure of code is irrelevant as long as it is readable and get the job done.

Comment: @Max It does not show the CPU as a percentage, Like task manager

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the code and it shows the individual results now.

Comment: @Inferno The CPU attribute is the percentage and the values can be modified to look however you like... The CookedValue attribute of the CounterSamples object contains the percentage in this specific case and this is assigned to the CPU attribute.

Comment: So it is not possible?

Comment: @Inferno what are you talking about?

Comment: I mean, I can't figure out what percentage of CPU this program uses?

Comment: I tested your code many times, but the result is different from what the task manager shows

Comment: @Inferno You get the data like in the task managers detail tab. Task manager readings are not really representative, there are other, more precise solutions. Task manager updates its values constantly, if you don't do it as well you won't get the same results... Obviously. Task manager does an average calculation so you won't get the same readings. If want task manager data, open task manager